# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении? (1001)

Tags: пунктуация

В одном из таких разделов есть публикация об Австрии, ее достопримечательностях, городах, столице – Вене, которая входит в список красивейших мест в мире, а также о туристических услугах этой страны, её архитектуре, культурной и духовной жизни.

Comment: "Туристические услуги страны" не очень убедительно звучит; можно попробовать "о туристических услугах, предлагаемых в этой стране" и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

В одном из таких разделов есть публикация об Австрии, ее достопримечательностях, городах, **столице Вене**, которая входит в список красивейших мест в мире, а также **о развитии туризма в этой стране**, о её архитектуре, культурной и духовной жизни.